# Daily loss of internet connection at home

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Ever since I bought a new PC I have been experiencing loss of internet connection on it. It might be affecting other devices but it is only noticeable on my PC. For example, when I'm in a Microsoft Teams meeting, the connection will suddenly drop.

I couldn't find any logs about the events that occurred. I tried updating my network adapter, updating router software, restarting the router, etc.

My network consists of 2 routers. The first router which I will call 'Router A' is connected to the modem, and the other one which I will call 'Router B', is connected to the ethernet wall outlet and to my PC.
The DHCP server is disabled on Router B and I added the Router B MAC address to the DHCP reservation list which is on Router A in hopes it would fix things. Router B is also set up as an access point and I've connected the LAN port of Router B to the ethernet wall outlet. I'm getting a Wi-Fi signal as well as internet by cable.

As far as I know the ethernet wall outlet goes towards a switch. From this switch there is a cable to Router A and multiple other rooms which have their own ethernet wall outlets.

I've made sure Router B is on the same subnet as Router A and that all cables are not loose by accident.

I've tried almost everything but I have no idea what could be at fault here. I've tried pinging the Google server whilst disconnecting, which resulted in "Request timed out" messages.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Do a traceroute during the outage to identify the hop at fault.

Comment: You said you have two routers, then several times you say "my router" without specifying which of the two routers you're talking about. This makes your question hard to follow. Can you edit your question to clear that up?

Comment: Also, you said your second router is connected to an Ethernet wall outlet, but you didn't describe how that Ethernet line connects to the rest of the network, and I don't want to make any assumptions, so it would be helpful if you could include that information also (when you edit your question).

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answers I've edited the question as you asked. If you still have any questions please let me know.

Comment: So with previous PC all was fine? Same network, same everything, just PC changed?

Comment: Yes exactly. Everything was fine up to the point I connected my PC